# Remove an already created DrawTextA inside a hooked application

Tags: c++, dll, hook, direct3d

I've been working on a DLL hook for a game that allows to modify some in game memory things to greater my knowledge in hooking and modifying memory etc. I've come to a point where i can't quite figure out how to continue!

I've created a font and displayed it to the screen using the below method..

```
LPD3DXFONT      g_pFont = NULL;

HRESULT WINAPI hkEndScene(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    if(g_pFont == NULL){
        D3DXCreateFontA(pDevice, 12, 0, FW_BOLD, 1, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Verdana", &g_pFont);
    }
    if(g_pFont != NULL)
    {
        RECT rect = { 10, 10, 500,200 };
        g_pFont->DrawTextA(NULL, "Text to draw to screen", -1, &rect, 0,tGreen);
    }
    return oEndScene(pDevice);
}
```

Now what i need to figure out is how I can remove that DrawTextA from the screen, or change it's text to something else. I have absolutely no clue how to do this!

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I didn't quite understand how EndScene worked! Looks like it's drawn at the end of every frame and I just need to do an if statement to get it to go away!

```
    if(g_pFont != NULL)
{
    //RECT struct - left,top,right,bottom in pixels
    if(g_timer < 2000){ 
    RECT rect = { 10, 10, 500,200 };
    g_pFont->DrawTextA(NULL, "Draw this and remove this", -1, &rect, 0,tGreen);
    }
}
```

g_timer is set to ++ inside of the hkDrawIndexedPrimitive thread.